# When to use $HTTP_POST_VARS['field'] and $_POST['field']?

Tags: php

What is the difference in using $HTTP_POST_VARS['field'] and $_POST['field']?
what makes the difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`$HTTP_POST_VARS` is the old (deprecated since PHP4.1.0) way of accessing POST data](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). You never use it nowadays, unless you are working on an ancient legacy application.

Comment: osCommerce: Is it "Ancient Legacy"?

Comment: @OMTheEternity depends on which version you are using. If they have this in their actively maintained trunk, then it's just poor code. You should use $_POST nowadays.

Comment: OSCommerce has some of the crappiest code I've ever seen. It's still a decent system all in all, but some parts of the code base give you goose bumps.